# CORS / Cross Origin Isolation / Google APIs

Tags: nginx, google-api, cross-origin-opener-policy, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-resource-policy

I'm trying to integrate the Zoom Web Video SDK into an existing web application, and SharedArrayBuffer has become a requirement for performance reasons, and in order to enable it the site has to implement Cross Origin Isolation. I've gone ahead and added the requisite configuration to NGINX, namely:

```
add_header 'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy' 'require-corp';
add_header 'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy' 'same-origin';
```

... but of course this has knock-on effects for the rest of the previously existing and working site. The Google APIs won't seem to load successfully anymore.

I changed my index.html to add the crossorigin attribute to the Google API script tag as follows:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer crossorigin></script>
```

... and in my javascript source code I have (paraphrasing and reducing complexity to get the the point):

```
gapi.load('client:auth2', function() { 
  gapi.client
  .init({
     client_id: 'MY-CLIENT-ID',
     cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
     discoveryDocs: ['https://classroom.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1'],
     scope: 'profile email'
  })
  .then(() => console.log('init finished'))
  .catch(e) => console.error('init failed', e));
});
```

In that code, gapi and gapi.client are well-defined, but the init call never completes (no console logs from the then or from the catch). Looking at the network tab in devtools shows a failed GET request to:

> https://content-classroom.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1& ... and bunch of other stuff i'm not sure if is sensitive so am omitting

When you dive into the response, it shows:

> To use this resource from a different origin, the server needs to
> specify a cross-origin resource policy in the response headers:
>
> - Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: same-siteChoose this option if the resource and the document are served from the same site.
> - Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: cross-originOnly choose this option if an arbitrary website including this resource does not impose a
>   security risk.

Obviously, I can't control what Google's servers do, but can anyone instruct me as to how I can get this to work correctly. This only goes awry in the presence of my NGINX configuration change at the start of this post.

**Update**

I partially worked around this by fetching the discovery document for the API separately and passing the result into the gapi.client.init method instead of the URL. However, while I don't get the aforementioned outcome in the network tab of devtools anymore, but I instead get weird / inconsistent results with responses like "popup_closed_by_user" and "popup_closed_by_browser" happening in response to my GoogleAuth.signIn call. If I remove the headers from NGINX it starts behaving as expected again. I don't understand what's going on with this.

Answer (score 1):

https://web.dev/cross-origin-isolation-guide/#enable-cross-origin-isolation
Visit that link and read through it.

It mentions that popup behavior is currently affected by enabling those headers which explains your behavior.

You'll have to read through and decide for yourself if that explains your issue.